# копирование файлов в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужно скопировать все файлы у которых в названии есть буква "f" со всей системы в отдельную папку
есть начало кода с выводом полных ссылок. помогите мне с написанием второй части кода для копирования этих фалов в одну папку. учитывая что у меня сотни текстовых файлов

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

for filename in glob.iglob('../**/*f*', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(filename)) and filename.endswith('.txt'):
        print(os.path.abspath(filename))

if len(filename) == 0:
    print("nothing")
else:
    save_dir = "C:\python\TXT"
    if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
        res = os.mkdir(save_dir)
        if res == OSError:
            print("cant create directory")
shutil.copyfile()
```

Comment: Вы пишете "все файлы, у которых в названии есть буква F", а потом `filename.endswith('.txt')` Вы уж решите, что вам надо - все файлы, или только текстовые.

Comment: Что делать, если у файлов из разных папок  одинаковые названия?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 4):

```py
import os
import glob
import shutil

# сюда будем сохранять все подходящие имена файлов
files_to_copy = []
for filename in glob.iglob('../**/*f*', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(filename)) and filename.endswith('.txt'):
        print(os.path.abspath(filename))
        # сохраняем в списочек
        files_to_copy.append(filename)

if len(filename) == 0:
    print("nothing")
else:
    save_dir = "C:\python\TXT"
    if not os.path.isdir(save_dir):
        res = os.mkdir(save_dir)
        if res == OSError:
            print("cant create directory")
    # копируем файлы по списку
    for f in files_to_copy:
        shutil.copy(f, save_dir)
```

Но есть подозрение, что в вашем изначальном коде лучше вместо:

```py
for filename in glob.iglob('../**/*f*', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(filename)) and filename.endswith('.txt'):
```

писать

```py
for filename in glob.iglob('../**/*f*.txt', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(filename)):
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, немного не в тему. Если интересно тестирование вашего api для битрикс пишите в телегу @karpov_an, мы на salesforce переходим, поэтому с битриксом могу делать что хочу